# Why does this code only compile with a redundant map()?

Tags: java, generics

I've come across an oddity I can't explain.

The following code (a minimal example) won't compile:

```java
class Test {
  interface I {}

  Optional<I> findOne(ArrayList<? extends I> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .findFirst();
  }
}
```

javac (version 11 at least) says:

```
error: incompatible types: Optional<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Optional<I>
        .findFirst();
                  ^
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends I from capture of ? extends I
```

However, I sort of randomly found that adding a seemingly redundant .map() call to the stream [**edit**: it's actually added to the Optional returned by findFirst()] compiles fine:

```java
class Test {
  interface I {}

  Optional<I> findOne(ArrayList<? extends I> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .findFirst()
        .map(a -> a);
  }
}
```

I'm curious about what is happening there that adding the .map() call lets it compile.

[I know that changing the method parameter to take an `ArrayList<I>` works, but that's not what I'm asking about.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Generics are invariant

The first does not compile because Java generics are **invariant**.

An `Optional<Dog>` is completely different to an `Optional<Animal>`, hence `Optional<...>` with `...` being the type your `?` captured is not compatible to `Optional<I>`.

To elaborate, consider the following example:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();

List<Animal> animals = dogs; // this does not compile, but pretend it would
animals.add(new Cat());

Dog dog = dogs.get(0); // should be safe, but its actually a cat!
```

---

### Upcast

But with the `map(a -> a)` you have an **implicit upcast** of the type, like `(Animal) dog` which makes this actually an `Optional<Animal>`. So `Optional<I>` instead of `Optional<...>` in your case.

So your `a -> a` lambda, which looks innocent actually is a method taking `Dog` (or `...` from `?` in your case) and giving out an `Animal` (or `I`):

```
a -> (I) a
```

Consider the following example

```
Optional<Dog> dog = Optional.of(new Dog());

Optional<Animal> animal = dog.map(d -> d);
```

which demonstrates exactly your situation. Because of invariance you can not just assign it, you have to actively convert it. And because of context, Java can implicitly cast the `d` to `Animal`. So the code is equivalent to

```
dog.map(d -> (Animal) d);
```

---

### Note

Note that the `map` method you call here is **not** the `map` from `Stream` but from `Optional`, which is the result of `findFirst`. So its purpuse is to map from an `Optional<X>` to an `Optional<Y>` by applying the given transformation.

Comment: Is adding the .map() also then equivalent to explicitly casting the return value to `(Optional<I>)`?

Comment: No. Due to invariance you can not cast a `List<Dog>` to a `List<Animal>` (see my example). They behave completely different and thus are strictly incompatible. The `map` converts the inner value, the `Dog` to an `Animal`. And based on that creates a new `Optional` with that new value. Example `Optional.of("hello").map(word -> word.length())` this will start with a `Optional<String>` and then end with `Optional<Integer>`, two completely unrelated types.